# Getting all EmployeeID's in dropdown list from mysql database?

Tags: php

In my case, I am getting only the EmployeeId which i have registered **latest** and not all the employeeId's from the table in database.

**Code :**

```
public function getEmployeeId() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["passwrd"])) {
        header("Location:index.php");
        // Cannot Access this page without Login.
    }
    if (empty($_POST)) {
        $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT EmployeeId FROM employeeprofile") or die("Query execution failed: " . mysqli_error());
        **while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {**
            $id = $row["EmployeeId"];
            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        }
    }
}
```

i am using this session value in  tag in my html form.

```
 <select name="EmployeeId" required autofocus class='form-control'>
     <option value=""> ----Select----</option>
     <?php
         if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
             echo "<option value = " . $_SESSION["id"] . ">" . $_SESSION["id"] . "</option>";
         }
     ?>
 </select>
```

Someone suggested me to check the array , but i am confused.

Comment: what is error here ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do can you please clear the question

Comment: You do get all the ID's, but you're overwriting the same variables `$id` and `$_SESSION['id']` on each iteration. That's why only the id from the last ID is stored.

Comment: i am getting only one employeeId from database in dropdown list not all  employeeId's which are in database

Comment: Like I said, You probably _do_ get all ID's, but since you're _overwriting the same variables_ in _each iteration_, only the _last_ is stored after your `while`-loop.

Comment: improve code output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently overwriting the ID on each iteration. You need to store them in an array in which you append each ID instead:

```
// Make this session item an array
$_SESSION['id'] = [];

$query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT EmployeeId FROM employeeprofile") or die("Query execution failed: " . mysqli_error());
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Push the id to the array
    $_SESSION['id'][] = $row["EmployeeId"];
}
```

Now you need to iterate through the array with the ID's when printing the options:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['id'] as $id) {
        echo "<option value='$id'>$id</option>";
    }
}
```

This should work, as long as you have `session_start()` in the top of your scripts.

I would probably not use sessions to store results like this, but I don't know enough of your code to be able to give you a good solution.

Comment: It Worked great.

Comment: @Rajat - Feel free to accept it since it worked for you

Comment: @Rajat Then accept this answer. This lets others know the question has been answered and those that may find this question later know which answer solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

i thik the problem is that you should retrieve data in array from query and you can apply foreach loop to print the employee.

first get all the employee

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT EmployeeId FROM employeeprofile") or die("Query execution failed: " . mysqli_error());
$result = query($query);
```

now print the retrieved employee in option field

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option value=" . $row["id"] . ">" . $row["id"] . "</option>"
   }
} else {
   echo "<option value="">No result found.</option>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me wouldn't advise to use sessioning, then to populate your `select` input, you do the below code, this is just a method of doing this anyway

```
    public function getEmployeeId() {
            if (!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["passwrd"])) {
                header("Location:index.php");
                // Cannot Access this page without Login.
            }
$ids = array();
            if (empty($_POST)) {
                $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT EmployeeId FROM employeeprofile") or die("Query execution failed: " . mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$ids[] = $row['EmployeeId']; //we populate our array here
}

            }
return $ids; //return the array here
        }
```

from your html you do this

```
<select>
   <option value="">Select</option>
  <?php 
    $ids = getEmployeeId();
    for($i=0;$i<count($ids); $i++){
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $ids[$i];?>"><?php echo $ids[$i];?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you are putting only last value of array in **$_SESSION["id"]**  variable

Change `$_SESSION["id"] = $id;` to `$_SESSION["id"][] = $id;`

and to print

```
if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
     foreach($_SESSION["id"] as $v){
        echo "<option value ='" . $v . "'>" . $v."</option>";
     }
}
```