# get Latest Registered Id?

Tags: php

**Code :**

**Want to have only latest registered employeeId in drop down list from database ?**

```
public function getEmployeeId() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["passwrd"])) {
            header("Location:index.php");
            // Cannot Access this page without Login.
        }
        if (empty($_POST)) {
            $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT EmployeeId FROM employees") or die("Query execution failed: " . mysqli_error());
            while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
                $id = $row["EmployeeId"];
                $_SESSION["ID"] = $id;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here is my HTML Code Snippet :**

```
 <td>
                    <select name="EmployeeId" required autofocus class='form-control'>
                        <option value=""> ----Select----</option>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION["ID"])) {
                            echo "<option value = " . $_SESSION["ID"] . ">" . $_SESSION["ID"] . "</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

Comment: please don't spam the SO . Instead of posting new question try to update your old one .which is asked yesterday . There you got almost four answer but you didn't reply for them ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733832/getting-all-employeeids-in-dropdown-list-from-mysql-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all EmployeeID's in dropdown list from mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733832/getting-all-employeeids-in-dropdown-list-from-mysql-database)

Comment: @Rajat on one question you say you are only getting latest, on another you say you want to get latest, but on both you post the same code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT MAX(EmployeeId) AS EmployeeId FROM employees
```

Comment: ...As long as the ID is of numeric type, and incremented on each registration, and the primary key of the table.

Comment: It Worked Fantastic

Comment: @Rajat Then accept this answer. This lets others know the question has been answered and those that may find this question later know which answer solved this problem